# Dynamically add a script to certain pages

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site that is obviously template driven. What javascript do I need to add if I want a script to load on a particular page? Preferably defined by the URL (unless there's a better way?).

IE: only load the script if URL="abc.net/123"

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('abc.net/123') != -1) {
  document.write('<script src="foo.js"><\/script>');
}
```

so that the script element is only added if the location includes "abc.net/123".

However, if you are in control of the server, it's much better to include the script there.

Answer (score 0):

> wp_enqueue_scripts is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that
>   are meant to appear on the front end. Despite the name, it is used for
>   enqueuing both scripts and styles.

In `WordPress` you may use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function to dynamically add any `script` 
on the `front end` with [wp_enqueue_scripts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hook. For example:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'custom-script', // script identifier
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js', // path
        array( 'jquery' ) // dependency
    );
}

// Register the handler
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

To detect a page (page/post) there are many functions available in `WordPress` but your `url` which is `abc.com/123` doesn't seem qualified for those functions (`is_home()`, `is_single()` etc) or I'm not sure what page is this so i would use something like this:

```
$Page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($page == 123) { // or '123' and only REQUEST_URI
    //add script
}
```

So, paste this code in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    $Page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ($page == 123) { // or '123'
        wp_enqueue_script('...'); // provide required args
    }
}

// Register the handler
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
```

Read the links provided in the answer for more information.